# need help choosing the right method of mysql DB sharding, clustering or partitioning

Tags: mysql, partitioning, cluster-computing, sharding

i am developing an application that will use three tables.
1 - 1 million rows of products.
2 - 500 million rows of users.
3 - 10 billion rows of products that the users like.
the tables will grow with the time but will stay around those numbers.
i want to choose the right method for this kind of DB.
i really don't know much about sharding, clustering or partitioning but if some of you can tell me the best solution for this problem i will focus on it and its will be a huge help.
i want only methods that support mysql and if i need multiple servers for this kind of DB?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can shard this data set pretty easily but you might not have to depending on the type of analysis you are trying to do.  If this is simply a history of what each user likes, then you can probably use [database partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) to partition the data by range on date, and then sub-partition on the user_id.

If you will frequently update the date (users can "unlike" things) then you probably need to look at sharding.  There is an example sharding implementation here: [Shard-Key-Mapper](http://code.google.com/p/shard-key-mapper).  You can execute distributed parallel queries over the dataset (like map/reduce for SQL) here: [Shard-Query](http://code.google.com/p/shard-query).

If you shard, I should suggest sharding by user_id and keeping the products table as the "shared" table which is duplicated on each shard.  You should use a directory based sharding method that allows you to move a user between shards.  All the information about a single user, and the information about what they like will be stored together on one shard.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you really don't want a noSQL solution like Hadoop, you can't avoid to get multiple database (here: MySQL) servers. And a MySQL replication doesn't provide in my opinion enough scalability for this kind of data, because the master will become the bottleneck. I'm also not a scalability professional, but I am currently also thinking of a nice solution for a similar problem on my side. I think I will go with a sharding solution where I partition my data over multiple nodes. I am just thinking about an intelligent way to create the mapping from data to shard. But this depends on your application how you want to make it. I think your 'product liking' data is a good candidate for partitioning, because it's so huge.

BTW: An interesting article **against** sharding: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1509-mr-moore-gets-to-punt-on-sharding